# Editor-in-chief sent an email to resubmit my manuscript

Tags: publications, research-process, journals, peer-review

I've submitted an article to an Elsevier-based journal and after one month, 
an email has been received from Editor-in-chief stating: "Please upload figures separately from manuscript and resubmit it as soon as possible".

**What does the email mean?**

**What will occur after resubmission?**

Comment: What exactly are you asking?  Why not just resubmit it with the figures separate, as asked?

Comment: What will happen to my article? Accepted or rejected? Does this email good or bad? I sent all figures and resubmited manuscrpit 1 week ago

Comment: Please edit your question to include what you are asking in your comment above. Although I voted to close as "unclear what you're asking", I would retract my close vote after you include the info.

Comment: I think you're reading too much into that e-mail; it doesn't seem have any other meaning than the request to resubmit the manuscript with the figures as separate documents. "I look forward to..." is a phrase for politeness.

Comment: But mentioned at this email "i look forward to receiving your revised manuscript as soon as posible

Comment: "revised manuscript" probably means figures separately from manuscript.

Comment: Related question: [What does the typical workflow of a journal look like?](http://academia.stackexchange.com/q/55665/546)

Comment: No one has reviewed your paper yet. It means they wasted one month because someone at the editorial office has OCD. As a reviewer, I have never thought "OMG how can I possibly review the paper in this state? It has the figures inline instead of separated from the manuscript. Outrageous! Completely unreadable!"

Comment: @Federico Poloni thank you so much Dr. You are the best reviewer in the world. I appreciate your help and your attention to my question.

Answer (score 11):

It means that you should resubmit the manuscript with figures separately, as it is probably stated somewhere in the journal's instructions for authors.

They probably cannot deal with the formatting otherwise, and depending on field and journal I would say that it is quite likely that your manuscript has not yet been reviewed, as stuff not living up to guidelines tends to go to the bottom of the pile.

Comment: But mentioned at this email "i look forward to receiving your revised manuscript as soon as posible"

Comment: @Sina That's a polite phrase saying that you are requested to do upload the revised manuscript as soon as possible. It doesn't say anything about the chance of your manuscript for publication in this journal.

Comment: It is just a pleasantry. Like writing 'Kindest regards', even though you probably could give a kinder regard.

Comment: Thank you @Ronald, i thought my artcile is in review process.

Comment: I don't think there is any formatting involved here. They are at the stage where they just have to take the pdf and forward it to a couple of reviewers.

Comment: @Sina "i thought my artcile is in review process" Unfortunately, you were wrong. The editor-in-chief has send you a simple request. Just do as they ask. There's nothing to be gained by trying to analyze this situation.